# html2canvas can use scale or filter: blur(10px) when take screenshot?

Tags: html2canvas

Same question like the title:

html2canvas can use scale or filter: blur(10px) from image when take screenshot?

Example:

```
filter: blur(10px);
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-o-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "blur", but i'm sure "scale" is not supported. There is a pull request about this tho. You can find it here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/127